# How to rotate 360° day/night cycle image based on the real time of the day?

Tags: javascript, unix, time, gml

**the day/night circle example:**
https://i.ibb.co/fFskJ28/exmp.png

I want the day/night circle image *(example in the link above)* to rotate based on the real time (+1 UTC, no winter/summer time adjustments). The times you see in the image are already based on the +1 UTC time. 
I already achieved to make this work in my game maker project, but now I also want this day/night circle image on my website so visitors can also see the day/night cycle live there.

I have already the working code written in GML, but now I want it in PHP/Javascript, and I know not much about Javascript, but I guess it is a must to use if I want the day/night cycle image to rotate in live time.

So here's my working code written in GML:

```
//written in GML
// unix_timestamp([datetime])
//
//  Returns a Unix timestamp for the current time
//  or optionally given GameMaker datetime value.
{
    var timezone = date_get_timezone();

    date_set_timezone(timezone_utc);

    if (argument_count > 0) {
        var datetime = argument[0];
    } else {
        var datetime = date_current_datetime();
    }

    var timestamp = round(date_second_span(25569, datetime));

    date_set_timezone(timezone);

    return timestamp;
}
```

The following part is a bit messy but does all what I want, making the variables 'hour' and 'minute' equal to the real time hour/minute in my country (+1 UTC)

```
//written in GML

rtime = unix_timestamp();

//removing all seconds from 1 jan 1970 00:00 - 1 jan 2019 00:00 (UTC+1 Amsterdam)
rtime2 = (rtime - 1546300800+3600);//the +3600 is meant to add 1 hour to
 equalise to the UTC+1 time


//remove all remaining days
{
while (rtime2 >= 86400)
   {
   rtime2 -= 86400;
   }
}

dtime = unix_timestamp();

//removing all seconds from 1 jan 1970 00:00 - 1 jan 2019 00:00 (UTC+1 Amsterdam)
dtime2 = (dtime - 1546300800+3600);//the +3600 is meant to add 1 hour to
 equalise to the UTC+1 time


//number of days from 1 jan 2019 00:00
day_unf = (dtime2 / 86400);
day = (floor(day_unf) + 1);

//count all remaining hours
hour_unf = (rtime2 / 3600);

hour = (floor(hour_unf))

qtime = unix_timestamp();

//removing all seconds from 1 jan 1970 00:00 - 1 jan 2019 00:00 (UTC+1 Amsterdam)
qtime2 = (qtime - 1546300800+3600);//the +3600 is meant to add 1 hour to
 equalise to the UTC+1 time

//remove all remaining days
{
while (qtime2 >= 86400)
   {
   qtime2 -= 86400;
   }
}

removar = (hour * 60)

//count all remaining minutes
minute_unf = (qtime2 / 60);
minute_unf2 = (minute_unf - removar);

minute = (floor(minute_unf2))


xtime = unix_timestamp();

//removing all seconds from 1 jan 1970 00:00 - 1 jan 2019 00:00 (UTC+1 Amsterdam)
xtime2 = (xtime - 1546300800+3600);//the +3600 is meant to add 1 hour to 
equalise to the UTC+1 time


//remove all remaining days
{
while (xtime2 >= 86400)
   {
   xtime2 -= 86400;
   }
}

rem = (minute * 60);

rem2_unf = (hour * 3600);

xtime3 = (xtime2 - rem);
second = (xtime3 - rem2_unf);

if hour == 24{
    hour = 0;
}
```

```
//written in GML
pre1 = 15 * hour;
pre2 = 0.25 * minute;
pre3 = pre1 + pre2;
cycle_angle = pre3;
//cycle_angle is always a number between 0-360 and is used below to draw the day/night circle image in the right rotation degree.

draw_sprite_ext(spr_day_night_cycle,0,960,80,image_xscale*1.5,image_yscale*1.5,cycle_angle,c_white,image_alpha);
```

Since the image is a circle of 360° degree, and it represents the time of one whole day of 24 hour, every passing hour is equal to 15° rotating, and every minute is equal to 0.25° rotating.
When the time is 18:30 for example, it rotates 277,5° (15 * 18 + 30 * 0.25) to represents that it is will day but the sunset is close.

**So my questions are:**

**Question 1:** How can I make the variables  'hour' and 'minute' in PHP/Javascript based on the real time hour/minute in my country (+1UTC, no winter/summer time adjustment needed)

**Question 2:** If I succeed in question 1, how can I rotate my day/night circle image on the website based on the 'hour' and 'minute' variables like I did in GML? *(see GML example below)*

```
//written in GML
pre1 = 15 * hour;
pre2 = 0.25 * minute;
pre3 = pre1 + pre2;
cycle_angle = pre3;
//cycle_angle is always a number between 0-360 and is used below to draw the day/night circle image in the right rotation degree.

draw_sprite_ext(spr_day_night_cycle,0,960,80,image_xscale*1.5,image_yscale*1.5,cycle_angle,c_white,image_alpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //returns a string
```

There's many more functions in the DateTime object; [read about it here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

In JS:

```
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
```

You can then use those values and use CSS to rotate an image from 0-360 degrees using `transform: rotate(360deg);`